# React video player progress bar for multiple videos behaves strange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, html5-video

I am creating a react application where I am using three videos with custom progress bar for each one to be displayed at screen. I am facing a problem with progress bar update for all the three videos. When one video is fully played it's progress works fine but as soon as second video start playing, It also updates the bar width together (video1 and video2). I am using "timeupdate" event for updating the video progress bar.

`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  var v3 = `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4`;
  var v2 = `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4`;
  var v1 = `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4`;

  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);
  const [currentVideo, setCurrentVideo] = React.useState('');
  const [barCompleted, setBarCompleted] = React.useState<any>({
    myBar1: false,
    myBar2: false,
    myBar3: false,
  });
  const videoRef = React.useRef<any>();
  const progress1 = React.useRef<any>();
  const progress2 = React.useRef<any>();
  const progress3 = React.useRef<any>();
  const myBar1 = React.useRef<any>();
  const myBar2 = React.useRef<any>();
  const myBar3 = React.useRef<any>();

  const handleOnEnded = () => {
    videoRef.current.removeEventListener('timeupdate', () => {});
    // setBarCompleted(prev=>{myBar1:true,...prev})
    setId((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  const getVideoById = (id) => {
    if (id == 1) {
      setCurrentVideo(v1);
    } else if (id == 2) {
      setCurrentVideo(v2);
    } else if (id == 3) {
      setCurrentVideo(v3);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getVideoById(id);
  }, [id]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    videoRef?.current?.load();
    configureProgress(id);
  }, [currentVideo, id]);

  const configureProgress = (id) => {
    videoRef?.current?.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
      // console.log(e.target.currentTime);
      let i = 0;
      if (i == 0) {
        i = 1;
        // var elem = document.getElementById('myBar1');
        let width = 1;
        let sid = setInterval(frame, 1000);
        function frame() {
          if (videoRef.current.ended || width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(sid);
            i = 0;
            if (id == 1) {
              progress1.current.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
              myBar1.current.style.width = 0 + '%';
            } else if (id == 2) {
              progress2.current.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
              myBar2.current.style.width = 0 + '%';
            } else if (id == 3) {
              progress3.current.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
              myBar3.current.style.width = 0 + '%';
            }
          } else {
            width = Math.ceil(
              (videoRef.current.currentTime / videoRef.current.duration) * 100
            );
            if (id == 1) {
              myBar1.current.style.width = width + '%';
              console.log('width update id1');
            } else if (id == 2) {
              myBar2.current.style.width = width + '%';
              console.log('width update id2');
            } else if (id == 3) {
              myBar3.current.style.width = width + '%';
              console.log('width update id3');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="progress-container">
        <div id="myProgress1" ref={progress1}>
          <div id="myBar1" ref={myBar1}></div>
        </div>
        <div id="myProgress2" ref={progress2}>
          <div id="myBar2" ref={myBar2}></div>
        </div>
        <div id="myProgress3" ref={progress3}>
          <div id="myBar3" ref={myBar3}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {currentVideo && (
        <video
          autoPlay={true}
          controls
          muted={true}
          id="myVideo1"
          width={300}
          height={250}
          ref={videoRef}
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
          onEnded={handleOnEnded}
          preload="metadata"
          playsInline
        >
          <source src={currentVideo} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`

```
.progress-container {
  display: flex;
}
#myProgress1,
#myProgress2,
#myProgress3 {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar1,
#myBar2,
#myBar3 {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
}
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXgOi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usYQq.png)

I am expecting that "timeupdate" event should not run for second video as it also updates width for previous video(1st video).

Comment: I don't use React but I wonder if `videoRef?.current?.addEventListener` is messing things up. Once you attach an Event listener it remains active, so here you keep adding listeners to a new video until all 3 videos are each listening for time update at the same time. You need to also **remove** the now unwanted (or un-needed) listeners.

Comment: Maybe make a function, whose job is to remove (reset) all the event listeners from all the `videoRef?` then it finally adds only to the one you want. Something like `setListeners( 3 );` where the connected function `function setListeners ( id )` will first remove listeners from all known 3 videos and then finally re-adds a listener to the one whatever video is referenced by the function's input `id` number...

Comment: PS: It might be easier if you don't trap the eventListener's handling function inside `configureProgress`. Try using `videoRef?.current?.addEventListener('timeupdate', myFunctionName, false );` then you can have a separate function `myFunctionName` which can be called anytime from anywhere, even from some `setListeners` function.

Comment: I got the solution instead for setting multiple times timeupdate event, I have simply put in the video tag like here... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ewtzlm?file=App.tsx